# Disabling link button if textarea is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have basic button click that appends text a draggable div. In order for the button event to trigger, text has to be introduced to the textareafield. This is just a very basic way to validate for empty fields. It works well with button. The issue is now I am using a `link button` but I am trying to disable it by using `e.preventDefault()` but it is not working. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bullseye2346/0wbnud4k/55/)

```
$('.form-control').prop('disabled',true);
$('textarea').keyup(function (e){
        //$('#button').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);
        $('#button').prop( this.value == "" ? e.preventDefault() : false);
});
```

HTML

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter Text Here!"></textarea>
<br/>
<!--input type="button" id="button" disabled="disabled" value="Add Div with Text" /-->
<a href="#" id="button" role="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Post Sticky</a>
<br/>
<div>
    <div class="middle-side empty"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: The event that is preventable is that of the default action of the keyup on the text area.  In short, you're in the wrong scope with e.  You also can't attach an event to a button/link with a property call like that.   If you don't want the #button link to link, you should specify it .on('click' function(){}); in a listener of it's own.   Frankly, the entire method above is confusing and i'm not 100% sure what your actual goal is with putting text in a block to validate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check for `textarea` value and prevent behaviour on `#button` click handler if `textarea` value is incorrect (for example, is empty).

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/58/)

```
$('#button').click(function (e)
{
    if ($('textarea').val() == "")
    {
        return false;
    }
    ... other code
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially all you should have to do is check the value of the textarea first, in your buttons event handler. You can do so like this:

```
var text = $('textarea').val();
if(text == ''){
    return;
}
```

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/57/

Edit: You could also replace the `return;` with a `preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little something that may help you out, not just with the background functionality, also with the visual styling.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    function changeMyBTN(a) {
        if (a == false) {
            //Adds a Class name for the visual styling
            $('a[id="button"][role="button"]').addClass('aBTNdisabled');
            //Capture and prevents events to the BTN
            $('a[id="button"][role="button"][class="aBTNdisabled"]').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();});
        } else {
            //Remove class name if BTN should be enabled
            $('a[id="button"][role="button"]').removeClass('aBTNdisabled');
        }
    }
    $('textarea').keyup(function (e){
        if ( $(this).val() != "" ) {
            //Enables BTN
            changeMyBTN(true);
        } else {
            //Disables BTN
            changeMyBTN(false);
        }
    });
    /* This captures the mouse event if BTN is enabled */
    $('a[id="button"][role="button"]:not([class="aBTNdisabled"])').click(function() {
        /* Create the event action when clicking the link btn */
        //document.location.href="http://www.google.com";
        alert($('textarea').val());
    });
    /* Sets the default state of the btn */
    changeMyBTN(false);

});
```